# Copying all new files but last modified from location A to location B

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a VBScript to copy every X minutes files from location A to location B.
My conditions are: copy all new files (that don't exist in the destination folder) and don't copy the last modified file.
In order to do that, I created a list that sorts all files by last modified date.

I created the following script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim is_first
is_first = 1
Set list = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
strOriginFolder = "C:\Users\Shelly\Desktop\test"
strDestinationFolder = "C:\Users\Shelly\Desktop\test2"
list.Fields.Append "name", 200, 255
list.Fields.Append "date", 7
list.Open

For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder(strOriginFolder).Files
    list.AddNew
    list("name").Value = f.Path
    list("date").Value = f.DateLastModified
    list.Update
Next
list.Sort = "date DESC"

list.MoveFirst
For Each objFile in objFSO.GetFolder(strOriginFolder).Files
    If is_first = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo list("date").Value & vbTab & list("name").Value
        WScript.Echo ("\n")
        WScript.Echo list("name").Value
        WScript.Echo ("\n")
        WScript.Echo objFile.Path
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(strDestinationFolder & "\" & list("name").Value) Then
            objFSO.CopyFile list("name").Value, strDestinationFolder & "\" &
            list("name").Value
        End If
    End If
    is_first = 0
    list.MoveNext
Next
list.Close
```

Now I know that I have a problem with the most importand line:

```
objFSO.CopyFile list("name").Value, strDestinationFolder & "\" & list("name").Value
```

But I don't know how to use `objFSO.CopyFile` with the sorted list. The print from `objFile.Path` and from `WScript.Echo list("name").Value` are different of course.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "all new files except the last modified". Do you want to copy only the files that don't already exist in the destination folder and omit everything else? Or do you want to copy all new files except for the newest one of them?

Comment: there are 2 condition
1- copy all files that doesnt exist in destination folder strDestinationFolder
2- dont copy the most recet modified file -because it is still been writen to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a real need to store the full list of files in memory just to discard the newer one. You can simply iterate over the file list ensuring you don't copy the newer one.

```
Option Explicit

' Source and target folder configuration
Dim sourceFolderPath, targetFolderPath
    sourceFolderPath = ".\source"
    targetFolderPath = ".\target"

Dim targetFolder, testFile, newerFile, copyFile
    ' At the start there is not a new file nor a file to copy
    Set newerFile = Nothing 
    Set copyFile = Nothing 

    With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ' Get a full reference to target folder 
        targetFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName( targetFolderPath )
        ' Iterate over source file list
        For Each testFile In .GetFolder(.GetAbsolutePathName( sourceFolderPath )).Files
            ' Only process a file if it does not exist on target folder
            If Not .FileExists(.BuildPath( targetFolder, testFile.Name )) Then 
                If newerFile Is Nothing Then 
                    ' Is it the first file we see? Remember it as we still don't know 
                    ' if it is the newer one
                    Set newerFile = testFile 

                ElseIf testFile.DateLastModified > newerFile.DateLastModified Then 
                    ' We have found a file newer than the previously seen 
                    ' Select the previous one to copy and remember this new file
                    Set copyFile = newerFile
                    Set newerFile = testFile 

                Else 
                    ' Current file is not the newer one, copy it
                    Set copyFile = testFile 

                End If ' newerFile

                ' Is there a file to copy?
                If Not (copyFile Is Nothing) Then 
                    WScript.Echo "Copying " & copyFile.Path & " to " & .BuildPath( targetFolder, copyFile.Name ) 
                    copyFile.Copy .BuildPath( targetFolder, copyFile.Name )
                    Set copyFile = Nothing 
                End If ' copyFile

            End If ' FileExists
        Next ' testFile
    End With ' FileSystemObject
```